# Send request without server response

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've written controller's method in Spring-MVC:

```
@RequestMapping("/products/change.htm")
    public void changeCost() throws SQLException
    {
        ProductDAOImpl mapping = new ProductDAOImpl();
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("Перфоратор");
        product.setCost(432);
        mapping.updateProduct(product);
    }
```

But after him, tomcat trying to find `change.jsp` and generate response. I just execute this method on server and get no response. How is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837907/what-to-return-if-spring-mvc-controller-method-doesnt-return-value

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not done anything with the response. you have mapped the `/products/change.htm"` url to the `changeCost()` method.

If you need to set some response, just add an attribute or try to redirect it ,

```
@RequestMapping("/products/change.htm")
    public ModelAndView changeCost() throws SQLException
    {
        ProductDAOImpl mapping = new ProductDAOImpl();
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("Перфоратор");
        product.setCost(432);
        mapping.updateProduct(product);
        String map="successful";
        return new ModelAndView("yourJspName", "message", map);
    }
```

It a returns the object of the `ModelAndView` class. You can print it in the jsp .

Hope this helps !!