# Why does @ResponseBody on a void method with Spring MVC show no element found in the Firefox console?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller that I am calling via JQuery.ajax.

The mapping in the controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void remove(@RequestParam("value1") String value1,
                   @RequestParam("value2") String value2)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appserver/model/remove',
    data: { value1: value1, value2: value2 },
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    success: function() {
      // do something on success
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // do something on error
    }
  });
```

The POST call completes successfully with HTTP status 200. However, in the Firefox console the following is output:

```
no element found ... myscript.js:1
```

If I change my controller to return a boolean then this error disappears. However, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837907/what-to-return-if-spring-mvc-controller-method-doesnt-return-value) having @ResponseBody on a method with void return type is valid.

Is there anything I can change to remove this message?

Comment: When you clicked on the file, you performed a get request to the server for the asset to be loaded from that file. That's what invoked the get request. The server responded and said this file does not support get requests. It may support other request, however, such as post.

Comment: Of course! OK so I'm going to edit my question as I don't understand why no element found is output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [JQuery Bugs](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13450) and in [Firefox Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521301), it is a Firefox problem that occurs when  response entity body is null.

To fix it, you have to return such a ResponseEntity in your Controller method.

Try to add **dataType: 'text'** in your request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appserver/model/remove',
    data: { value1: value1, value2: value2 },
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function() {
      // do something on success
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // do something on error
    }
  });
```

and modify your Controller to return a **ResponseEntity** with a String as first parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> remove(@RequestParam("value1") String value1,
                   @RequestParam("value2") String value2)
{
  // do stuff
return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK!!!",HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
```

}