# Spring POST Request IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, http

I use a JAVA REST Service in Spring. When I want to save a HTML Form (and send it to the server), I recieve this exception:

> 2015-05-29 14:00:20.853  WARN 2623 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate serialization for type [void]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate standard serializer (of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer): Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory can not access a member of class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer with modifiers "private"

Comment: Please code of `KPIMetricDTO` and your configs

Comment: include `BaseDTO` code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i know a bit time has gone now, but i solved it thanks to

[Migration of Spring from 3.2 to 4.1.1: trouble with JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718431/migration-of-spring-from-3-2-to-4-1-1-trouble-with-json-serialization)

the magic code line was:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
```

at the Controller, because he returned "void", say nothing. This responses the "OK" message and so it works now :) thanks for your help anyway