# jQuery Ajax request with error 404 (not found) but it works

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm sending a jQuery AJAX request to the server, but the browser's console tells me that the page is not found. Still, my Spring MVC signature mapping the requested URL is executed, and yet the `done` part of the AJAX function is not.

Here is the relevant code:

Javascript:

```
    var content = $(data).filter("#wrapper-email-content");
    $.ajax({
        url : '/sendEmail',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            content: content.html()
        }
    }).done(function(){
        console.log("Finished")
    });
```

Spring MVC Signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void sendEmail(
    HttpServletRequest request, String content) {

    UserTO user = (UserTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("USER");
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String title = "Your order";
    Email.sendEmail(title, email, content, null, null, null);
}
```

So, in the code, the email is sent, meaning that sendEmail method is executed, but I still get the Error 404: not found from the AJAX request, and "Finished" is not printed in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're sure it's a 404, and that it isn't just the request that times out because there is nothing being returned from the server ?

Comment: What your sendEmail method returning\

Comment: The method returns nothing (void), it's just a request to ask the server to send an email, it doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: The error is: POST http://localhost:8000/catalog/sendEmail 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then try just outputting something on the server, ajax generally requires a response and a closing of the connection, before the success handler fires.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, but what do you mean by outputting something on the server?

Comment: I mean use `@ResponseBody` and return a string, or something, to the client, otherwise the ajax call never completes, it's waiting for data to be returned, or at least the connection to close. As to why your server is sending a 404 header, I don't know, but could be the same thing, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is annotating your method with

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
```

see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839817/954602 for the example.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's a better solution for what I want, even though the other ones work as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail",headers="Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,String> sendEmail(
    HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String content) {
    Map<String,String> statusMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
    UserTO user = (UserTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("USER");
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String title = "Your order";
    Email.sendEmail(title, email, content, null, null, null);
    statusMap.put("status","Mail sent successfully");
    return statusMap;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error message saying that @RequestBody cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Even though I still get an error when I add @RequestBody, returning something like this solved my problem. Is it always necessary to return something to an AJAX request? Can't I just use a void method?

Comment: add headers to @RequestMapping it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see solution posted for [What to return if Spring MVC controller method doesn't return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837907/what-to-return-if-spring-mvc-controller-method-doesnt-return-value)

Not familiar with MVC Spring, but you probably need to return a success status code yourself:

```
public String sendEmail(
    HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String content) {

    UserTO user = (UserTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("USER");
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String title = "Your order";
    Email.sendEmail(title, email, content, null, null, null);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```