# Webhook to collect a JSON: Request method POST not supported

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-security

I'm writing a controller with Java for a webhook URL that receives a POST method call, with a JSON body, that I need to collect.

This is a simplified version of the controller, with Spring annotations:

```
@RestController
public class MyWebhoook {

    @PostMapping("/my-webhook")
    public void getMyJson(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json) {
    System.out.println("WebHook collected JSON: " + json);
    }
}
```

I test it with Postman sending this JSON:

`Header: Content-Type / application/json`

```
{
    "webhookKey" : "tranviaVermellCostaAvall", 
    "token" : "xx",
    "channelId": 1,
    "propertyId": "999999",
    "status": "new",
    "reservationId": "111211221",
    "reservationStatus" : 1
}
```

And I get this answer:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-09T07:23:38.093+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/my-webhook"
}
```

The server log, gives some more information:

`Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/my-webhook}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7756c3cd`

I've tried those different approaches, with the same result:

1. `@RequestMapping(value = "/my-webhook", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)` instead of the `@PostMapping("/my-webhook")` annotation.
2. Modelling the received JSON as a java object instead of the `Map<String, Object> json`.
3. Using HttpServletRequest instead of the @RequestBody annotation, trying to read the request as a String.

**I do not understand the reason why the POST method is not allowed**. Any help, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try mark your method with @ResponseBody, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837907/what-to-return-if-spring-mvc-controller-method-doesnt-return-value

Comment: None of the proposed solutions in that pointed StackOverflow answer, work at my side. Surprisingly, other developers copying my code get it working. Maybe the problem comes from this Jackson class, which my system takes as default `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConvert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the **CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) security configuration**. The path of the webhook, has to be taken out of the CSRF control. Otherwise, the POST request doesn't pass the CSRF control.

This is a simplified extract of the security settings:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http
            .csrf()
                 .ignoringAntMatchers("/my/webhook")
```

Answer (score 1):

I added {} between your method and got a 200 as return. I added the pictures below on what code, request and console output i got.

[image: Code and request]
[image: console]

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code to my spring boot app, worked perfectly via postman...

API:

```
@PostMapping("/my-webhook")
  public void getMyJson(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json) {
  System.out.println("WebHook collected JSON: " + json);
}
```

RequestBody:

```
{
    "webhookKey" : "tranviaVermellCostaAvall", 
    "token" : "xx",
    "channelId": 1,
    "propertyId": "999999",
    "status": "new",
    "reservationId": "111211221",
    "reservationStatus" : 1
}
```

URL: http://localhost:8080/my-webhook

Try to:

- Update and Clean your project.
- Invalidate IDE cache and restart it, and try again.

Comment: Something may be wrong at my side, because even creating a new controller it doesn't work. Maybe you are using an alternative to this Jackson class:  `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConvert`,  which gets my system as default from the Jackson libriray, according to my settings.