# "Unexpected end of JSON input" on a Void SpringMVC Ajax Controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a SpringMVC/Thymeleaf applications where the following Ajax handling works perfectly fine if I return a `boolean`. However, as soon as the method is `void`, then I get the error
`Unexpected end of JSON input` in Firebug. This is a POST request.

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/addOrUpdate")
public void /*boolean works!*/ addOrUpdate(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
    service.addOrUpdateUserRoles(json);
    /*boolean works - return true;*/
}
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'text/plain', 
        url : 'addOrUpdate',  
        data : id 
 })
 .then(function() {
     //...
 })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     //...
 });
```

If I just remove `@ResponseBody` from the method definition, Thymeleaf complains,
`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [addOrUpdate], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

I followed the `ResponseEntity` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837907/what-to-return-if-spring-mvc-controller-method-doesnt-return-value), but it didn't help -- same error, JS goes into the Error section with Unexpected End of Input.

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/addOrUpdate")
public ResponseEntity addOrUpdate(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
    service.addOrUpdate(json);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dataType : 'json'`, you are telling jQuery that you're expecting JSON as a response. An empty response is no valid JSON, and the error message `Unexpected end of JSON input` is telling you exactly that.

If you intend not to return anything from the `addOrUpdate` controller method, remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation, as there is no response body, and stick to the `ResponseEntity` but use `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` instead to inform clients in your response that there's no content to be expected. Also, change your `dataType` to something that may be empty, like `'text'`.

Comment: I did everything as you said but returned HttpStatus.OK, as that seemed more informative, and it's working. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @geneb."no content" is a "successful" response status as well – in fact, it's the more informative one because it conveys additional information that no content is to be expected. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Successful_responses

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, the point of failure is input.
You need to send `json` format input.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'text/plain', 
        url : 'addOrUpdate',  
        data : {id: id}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL SOLUTION based on [digitalbreed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56139947/1005607)**

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/addOrUpdate")
public ResponseEntity<String> addOrUpdate(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
    try {
        service.addOrUpdate(json);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK); // No exceptions
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); // This will enable JS to catch the Exception from Ajax
    }
}
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : 'text', // Returns a ResponseEntity, not JSON (Void method)
        contentType : 'text/plain', 
        url : 'addOrUpdate',  
        data : somedata
 })
 .then(function() {
      //...
 })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //... - will come here for a ResponseEntity of 'Bad Request'
 });
```