# should I return the entire record again as a response from server to a POST when I do $update on an angular resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

In my `factory`

```
return $resource('rest/records/:id', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            // RestSQL has an extra struct around the array
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                return angular.fromJson(data).records;
            }
        },
        create: { method: 'POST' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'},
    });
```

Which is used by a `service` which is in turn used by a `controller`.

I get the correct record in the controller.

---

Then when I edit and want to save the record

I do `record.$update()`;

my rest POST is successful as I get a valid response from server.

But the response from server is just some kind of success message e.g. `"{ "number": 2 }"`.

Now I have an angular template which uses this records properties e.g. `{{record.image}}`

---

But as soon as I do record.$update();

records properties disapper and record now simply looks like

record = {"number" : 2}

---

So should I return the entire record as a response to the POST action or should I update in some other fashion so as to the record doesnt get its properties overwritten by the response from server?

---

A temporary way of getting around this of course is

```
$scope.temp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $scope.record);
$scope.temp.$update();
```

Comment: I do think it is OK, I do it all the time. See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797834/should-a-restful-put-operation-return-something.

Comment: oh...thanks...can you please comment on my temporary solution which is at the bottom of my question?

Answer (score 0):

I am returning the updated object on `POST`'s, `PUT`'s etc. (see also this: [Should a RESTful 'PUT' operation return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797834/should-a-restful-put-operation-return-something)) all the time. So,

- no problem with always returning the updated object in the response
- don't use tricks and more code to sove a problem that can be solved by applying a very simple solution (in this case, returning the updated object). I love those fixes: Simple solution, problem solved and code removed instead of adding things here and padding things there etc., making code unreadable und unnecessarily complex.