# Json put/get/post in Restful webservices not working

Tags: json, rest, post, get, put

I am trying to pass parameters to a server and extract the report in csv format. So the code i have has PUT/GET/POST in the order. I could get GET and POST work, but when i add PUT there is no error just blank screen.

```
String output1 = null;
URL url = new URL("http://<servername>/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/12345/parameters");
HttpURLConnection conn1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn1.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
conn1.setDoInput(true);
conn1.setDoOutput(true);
String body = "<parameters><parameter><id>0</id><answer><values><value>EN</value></values></answer></parameter></parameters>";
int len1 = body.length();
conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(len1));
conn1.connect();
OutputStreamWriter out1 = new OutputStreamWriter(conn1.getOutputStream());
out1.write(body, 0, len1);
out1.flush();
```

What i am trying to do is pass parameter EN to the report and refresh it, take the output in csv using GET. POST is used for login to the server. I could make GET and POST work and get the output in CSV but not refreshed one.

Appreciate very much any help here.

Thanks,
Ak

Answer (score 0):

What is the response code from the server when using PUT?

A PUT may not actually return a body to display on the screen; often times a PUT will only return a 200 or 204 response code. 204 would clearly mean that the server took the data and applied it, but is not sending you anything back, 200/201 may include a response, but maybe not. It depends on the folks who implemented the API.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html (section 9.6)

[Should a RESTful 'PUT' operation return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797834/should-a-restful-put-operation-return-something)

Comment: I am getting HTTP 401, which i guess is unauthorized or authentication errors. Any idea how and where i have to make changes?