# Put request in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a route like this --

```
Route::put('avote', 'voteController@avote')->middleware('auth');
```

I want to access this route from a ajax send request.

When i use this code --

```
$data = {/* some data here */};
$.post("/avote", $data, function(result) {
    $('#avote h2').html(result);
    $('#avote a span').css('color', 'orange');
    $('#avote a span').unwrap();
});
```

I get an error `method not allowed`. I know that it is the problem of method I used (used post not put)

I question is, is there any way i can get the information from `/avote` using ajax or any other scripts?

**Please dont suggest me to change the route request from `put` to `post`** or **Any other way to protect the `/avote` route**

> I used `Route::put()` beacuse i have a database update function in the route controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to `$.ajax()` function instead of `$.post` and provide `method` (`type`) property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/avote", 
    data: $data, 
    method: "PUT",
    // or type: "PUT", if your jquery version is prior to 1.9
    success: function(result) {
        $('#avote h2').html(result);
        $('#avote a span').css('color', 'orange');
        $('#avote a span').unwrap();
    }
});
```

Comment: now it is working correctly. Thanks, but now the problem is success function not working

Comment: Clarify please, what does it mean. Any errors in console?

Comment: no success message or anything. The request is working correctly but there is no response

Comment: See raw response, it nothing is outputted - check your route

Comment: May be this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797834/should-a-restful-put-operation-return-something

Comment: Is the request definitely getting accepted by your Laravel application? You can inspect the actual response and status code using your browser's dev tools.