# What Http code should I return when replacing a resource (file)

Tags: rest, http

I searched "HTTP code for replacing a resource" on Google but it really messes up with the keywords and don't give me the desired results. I have a file upload API and an interface that users interact to manage their images, two situations can occur: the user can replace an existing image or he can send more images. When the user replaces an existing image what HTTP code should I return?

Its's not a duplicate because I'm asking what HTTP code should I return when replacing a file not what people think about returning null in a PUT operation. If a person answered the possible duplicate question with information that answer my question that is another story, the question itself is not the same.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a RESTful 'PUT' operation return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797834/should-a-restful-put-operation-return-something)

Comment: According to the possible duplicate I should use PUT for replacing and POST for creating, is that correct? I would use POST for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a file upload API and an interface that users interact to manage their images, two situations can occur: the user can replace an existing image or he can send more images. When the user replaces an existing image what HTTP code should I return?

Probably a [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1); the client made a request, you handled it successfully.

http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

The actual implementation details of what the server actually did, or what the client intended, are not all that important; status codes are part of the meta data that allows *generic* http components to understand what's going on, so that they can behave appropriately (do we need to invalidate caches, should we pro-actively load some other resource, and so on).

Comment: I think that would be a good idea to have a "replaced http code" like we have 201 created .

Comment: I do not understand why this answer about 200 is accepted, but my answer is down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP code is mainly for HTTP server's status, eg: server error, file not found on server, etc.

In your application, your file upload API should return a JSON response to tell the user the upload result. and the HTTP code can always be 200 for succeeded operations. For failed operations, choose a code you like.

JSON response example:

```
HTTP 200
{
'result': 'ok',
}


HTTP 200
{
'result': 'replaced',
}

HTTP 403/405/etc
{
'result': 'failed',
'reason': 'file exists'
}
```

Ref:

[HTTP status code for update and delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete)

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Always returning 200 sounds like the opposite of REST.

Comment: Well, if someone do not like 200, just  define and use 4xx for special cases. No official HTTP code for such small case like "replacing".

Comment: I'm objecting to returning 200 for errors. The 4xx range is for client errors, not server errors.

Comment: well, I edited. My meaning is 200 for succeeded operations like "file replaced". For error codes, choose someone you like.