# Correct HTTP status code for PUT/POST method that does not update the document

Tags: http-status-codes

I have a HTTP PUT/POST method to update a document in the database. However, in certain conditions (for example, the input transaction timestamp is less than the timestamp on the document), the PUT/POST method does not apply the update. What is the appropriate HTTP status code to return in such cases, to notify the caller that the update did not happen?

Comment: You should look at [conditional requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827045/1513033)

Ideally, you should return a 400 status code (bad request) with a message indicating why the request failed. This allows anyone using your API to understand why the request was not successful.